# How to keep users from breaking buttons

Tags: hardware, product-design

Simple problem, if I have a large button a user can put their hand on then I'm afraid they can put too much force and break the electrical button underneath.

If I make the external button bottom out before the electrical button (push button switch) how do I ensure the electrical button always activates?

All the push button switches I've looked at either have a very small window where they are guaranteed to activate but haven't physically bottomed (limited over travel) out or no window at all (no over travel), you just have to bottom them out.

Am I worried for nothing? Should I just assume the push button switches are robust enough to handle the force?

This is a low cost consumer device application, and I'm trying to avoid adding extra mechanical complexity or big expensive switches.

FYI this is a rewrite of what I asked in the electronics stack exchange.

https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/449130/how-to-keep-users-from-breaking-push-button-switches

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because asking the same question on more than one site is discouraged, and there is nothing specific to the application of IoT here.

Comment: Fair enough, but there isn't really a good forum for this type of question, I looked through them all. I did read the meta on the subject and it did say it was allowed but to rephrase the question for the audience and link to the other question so that's what I tried to do. I just figured it might be a common issue in IoT type devices since IoT seems to include both the physical, electrical, and software side of such devices.

Comment: I feel your pain. There are quite a few questions that don't really fit - at least,t hey don't fit the main sites. Perhaps you could ask on Meta, or in Chat, although they get less visibility. Good luck